# Integration Technique

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have 6 huge expressions I want to integrate. Is there any way to break them piecewise and then send them for integration?
Two sample expression are:

Expression 1:

```
-((Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[1 - cq^2]
  E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (Ep + m) (-Eq + m) (Eq + 
   m) \[Pi]^2 (3 Ep Eq - 2 cp^2 Ep Eq - 2 cq^2 Ep Eq + 
   3 cp^2 cq^2 Ep Eq + cp^2 Ep m + 2 cq^2 Ep m - 
   3 cp^2 cq^2 Ep m + 2 cp^2 Eq m + cq^2 Eq m - 
   3 cp^2 cq^2 Eq m + 3 m^2 - cp^2 m^2 - cq^2 m^2 + 
   3 cp^2 cq^2 m^2 - 2 cp cq Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] - 
   2 (cp^2 (-1 + 2 cq^2) (Ep - m) (Eq - m) - 2 (Ep + Eq) m + 
      cq^2 (Ep - m) (-Eq + 
         m)) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + (-((-1 + cp^2) cq^2 (Eq - 
           m) m) - (-1 + cp^2) m^2 + 
      Ep (Eq + cp^2 cq^2 Eq - cp^2 (-1 + cq^2) m) + 
      2 cp cq Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2]) Cosh[
     2 \[Zeta]] + 2 cp Eq Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] - 
   2 cp cq^2 Eq Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] + 
   2 cp m Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] + 
   2 cp cq^2 m Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] + 
   2 cq Ep Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] - 
   2 cp^2 cq Ep Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] + 
   2 cq m Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] + 
   2 cp^2 cq m Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]] + 
   cp Eq Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   cp cq^2 Eq Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   cp m Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] - 
   cp cq^2 m Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   cq Ep Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   cp^2 cq Ep Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   cq m Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]] - 
   cp^2 cq m Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[2 \[Zeta]]))/(4 Ep Eq (m + 
   Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
   Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]])))
```

There are 4 of this type.

And two of the type given below:

```
(Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[
1 - cq^2] E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (Eq - m) (Ep + m) (Eq + m) \[Pi]^2 (Ep - 
cp^2 Ep + m + cp^2 m + (Ep + cp^2 Ep + m - cp^2 m) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + 
2 cp Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (Eq - cq^2 Eq + m + 
cq^2 m + (Eq + cq^2 Eq + m - cq^2 m) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + 
2 cq Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]))/(4 Ep Eq (m + 
Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]))
```

If there is any way to break them. Not manually.

The integrations are definite.

Comment: **The integrations are definite.** what is the integration variable and what are the limits? is it  just \[Zeta] ?

Comment: The integrations limits are:
Ep,Eq from -Infinity to Infinity.
cp,cq from 1 to -1.

The final result has to be in terms of zeta so no Integration on it

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the result of `Series[(Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[
      1 - cq^2] E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep -  m) (Eq - m) (Ep + m) (Eq + m) \[Pi]^2 (Ep - cp^2 Ep + m +     cp^2 m + (Ep + cp^2 Ep + m - cp^2 m) Cosh[\[Zeta]] +  2 cp Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (Eq - cq^2 Eq + m +   cq^2 m + (Eq + cq^2 Eq + m - cq^2 m) Cosh[\[Zeta]] +  2 cq Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]))/(4 Ep Eq (m +   Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp Sqrt[Ep^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq Sqrt[Eq^2 - m^2] Sinh[\[Zeta]])), {Eq, Infinity, 1}] // Normal` clearly demonstrates the divergence.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the expression, copy it to a notebook, copy the notebook cell by Copy as LaTeX and paste it via Ctrl+4 as a TeX expression in order to analyze by sight.

```
      Length /@ Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[intg]]
      {9, 6}
```

As a rational expression, it has to be converted into a sum of its numerator

```
    intg1 = intg // ExpandAll
     Head[intg1]
     Plus
     Lenght[intg1]
     224
```

By Timing, forget about doing that task for either intg or intg1 in a single step, except perhaps by paralellizing with some hundred kernels.

Have a look for the first term
intg2 = intg1[[1]] // FullSimplify

$$\frac{3 \pi ^2 \sqrt{1-\text{cp}^2} \sqrt{1-\text{cq}^2} \text{Ep}^2 \text{Eq}^2 e^{-\frac{\text{Ep}^2+\text{Eq}^2-2 m^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{4 \left(\text{cp} \sqrt{(\text{Ep}-m) (\text{Ep}+m)} \sinh (\zeta )+\text{Ep} \cosh (\zeta )+m\right) \left(\text{cq} \sqrt{(\text{Eq}-m) (\text{Eq}+m)} \sinh (\zeta )+\text{Eq} \cosh (\zeta )+m\right)}$$

```
 FreeQ[Numerator@intg2, \[Zeta]]
 True
```

Thats doable, just the inverse of a product of two exponentials:

```
   ( Denominator@intg2 // TrigToExp)[[-2 ;; -1]]
```

$$\left(\frac{1}{2} \text{cp} \left(e^{\zeta }-e^{-\zeta }\right) \sqrt{(\text{Ep}-m) (\text{Ep}+m)}+\frac{1}{2} \text{Ep} \left(e^{-\zeta }+e^{\zeta }\right)+m\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} \text{cq} \left(e^{\zeta }-e^{-\zeta }\right) \sqrt{(\text{Eq}-m) (\text{Eq}+m)}+\frac{1}{2} \text{Eq} \left(e^{-\zeta }+e^{\zeta }\right)+m\right)$$

I  suspect that this is a kind of pattern define it as a function

```
    f1[\[Zeta]_,{a_,b_,c_},{d_,e_,f_}]=
      Integrate[1/((a + b E^\[Xi] + c E^-\[Zeta]) *
         (d + e E^\[Xi] +  f E^-\[Zeta])), \[Xi]]
```

$$\frac{e^{2 \zeta } \left(\log \left(-e \ e^{\zeta +\xi }\right) \left(a\  e \ e^{\zeta }-b \left(d \ e^{\zeta }+f\right)+c e\right)+b \ \left(d \ e^{\zeta }+f\right) \log \left(e \ \left(e^{\zeta } \left(a+b \ e^{\xi }\right)+c \ \right)\right)-e \ \left(a \  e^{\zeta }+c\right) \log \left(d+e \ e^{\xi }+e^{-\zeta } f\right)\right)}{\left(a \  e^{\zeta }+c\right) \left(d \ e^{\zeta }+f\right) \left(a \  e \  e^{\zeta }-b \left(d \ e^{\zeta }+f\right)+c \ e\right)}$$

The denominator will be the same for many of the 223 terms

```
       Count[intg1, _?(FreeQ[Numerator[#], \[Zeta]] &)]
      60
```

The rest have numerators in sinh cosh up to power 2

```
     Union[Cases[  Numerator[ List @@ intg1],
       _?(!FreeQ[ #, \[Zeta]] &)]  ] /. 
          {__ Cosh[(n_ : 1 )* \[Zeta]] ->  Cosh[n \[Zeta]], 
            __ Sinh[(n_ : 1 )* \[Zeta]] ->  Sinh[n \[Zeta]]} // Union

        {Cosh[\[Zeta]], Cosh[2 \[Zeta]], Sinh[\[Zeta]], Sinh[2 \[Zeta]]}
```

So you have to integrate four more types.

Its a typical case where algorithms are light miles behind NI with its visual, instant learning, pattern recognizing capabilities (after some years training in math).